# NSApplication vs UIApplication

Tags: ios, uiapplication, nsapplication

What Is the difference between `UIApplication` and `NSApplication`? (As I am not getting it from their documentation...)
Can someone give me some useful links for detailed explanation about their differences?
Also, What is the key role of `AppNameAppDelegate.m` (and .h) in iOS Application?
Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIApplication is the iOS singleton application base class. NSApplication is the MacOS application base class.

Look at [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/differences-in-delegation.html) for a more detailed exploration on delegation and the implementations of UIApplication and NSApplication.